# select record that was not selected mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in mysql table. I want each record to be used only once. So I have "is_used" column.

But if someone select data before the update query he will not know that record is already used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a huge concern, you should look into the various [options for locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). This is a concurrency issue.

Comment: I am using MyISAM engine. what cani do?